# iOS Facebook App Link not working

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to set up App Links so that:

**a) When I tap on a link on the Facebook app, it opens my app if installed**

**b) If not installed, Facebook should *not* prompt the user to be directed to the App Store, and instead open the link in the in-app browser**

I have been experimenting with the `al:web:should_fallback` meta tag, but there have been some mixed results:

When `al:web:should_fallback` is set to `false`, scenario **a)** as above works correctly, as expected. Scenario **b)** is not fulfilled, as expected, because I've indicated that the system *should not* fall back to the web.

However, when setting `al:web:should_fallback` is set to `true`, even though the app is installed, scenario **a)** no longer works.

Why is this? I am under the impression that `al:web:should_fallback` controls scenarios for when the target app *is not installed*

**Some setup details:**

My website's meta tags are as follows (Actual values replaced by "_"):

```
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="_" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="_" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="_://_" />
```

There are no outstanding warnings on the [OG Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

There is only one warning on the [App Ads Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/), and this relates to Deferred Deep Linking, which according to the [App Links iOS documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios), is no longer supported

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution since September?

Comment: @Bogy unfortunately not. This issue _seems_ to be a bug on Facebook's side. As a workaround solution, I've fallen back to using scheme-based deeplinking, where my web app forcing the re-direct to the specified scheme.

Comment: Maybe you should try another url, I didn't know but when a URL shared on facebook at the first time, when you clicked if it's not worked, it's the same with the next times.